# The Right Way To Share Data Got From Server Across all View Controllers?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on the Authentication Part of my app flow. So in the Login View Controller when the user taps the Login  Button, network requests for the UserId. If a UserId is verified, then the user can Login. The Thing is all view controllers in my application are going to make network requests with that UserId , so I need a way to make the UserId accessible to all view controllers . How do I achieve that ?

Also what am I doing wrong? How would a Pro-Developer go with this situation ? Thanks for any help. Please also you can also share online resources. Thanks !!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your requirement like:

- If you don't want to persist `UserId` after app kill then you can use `Singleton Class`
- If you want to persist `UserId` after app kill and you are not so concern about the security then can use `UserDefault`
- If you want to persist `UserId` after app kill and you also wanted to follow guidelines to save sensitive data then can use `Keychain`

There are more options to use like `Database` `FileWrite`, so you need to choose wisely based upon your requirement.

You can find tons of tutorials for all above points

Answer (score 0):

You can save the `userID` & other `User details` you want to save through out the app by saving these in `NSUserDefaults`

```
var userID = "user1"
UserDefaults.standard.set(userID, forKey: "userID")
```

Now , whenever & In whichever screen you want to access these details, you can access like this.

```
if let userId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userID") {
    // use details here...
}
```